# Can CakePhp 2.x or 3.x be used to develop web app based on micro service architecture

Tags: rest, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, microservices, cakephp-2.8

I was evaluating PHP based frameworks for development of highly available and scalable applications based on micro service architecture.

I have not seen any documentation for using CakePhp 2.x or 3.0 for design and development of micro services. Where as Laravel ( which is another PHP MVC framework based on Symphony) seems to have these capabilities based on its Lumen modules or components.

It appears that CakePhp frameworks are only suited for design and development of big gigantic monolithic app.

Can anyone point me to a documentation or example about how to use CakePhp 2.x or 3.x for designing web apps based on Micro service architecture ?

Comment: I think there is a way for implementing REST API in cakephp http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html

Comment: `only suited for design and development of big gigantic monolithic app.` - kind of curious where this idea comes from, or what you mean by micro services such that you consider CakePHP inappropriate, micro frameworks are typically just a routing mechanism - which you can do with any framework (micro or not).

Comment: My question should be is it a qood framework choice for designing loosely coupled, cloud based application where client can be any javascript based frontend frameworks like AngularJS or React and backend is Restful based on CakePhp. I am looking at ease of use, complexity, development time and code size or memory footprint for horizontal scaling. Also how easy it is to containerize it in to docker containers, ability to support AJAX processing and REST based API development. Always better to have small code base for containerization.

Comment: That's basically the same question as "how can I generate json?".

Comment: I have been using CakePHP 3.4 for while now and it looks like they have made several improvement over CakePHP 2.X. Its much cleaner to write the REST API now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP is based on MVC patter and this allow you a lot of things, its true Cake is not the most popular PHP framework at the moment but I think this framework could be used to be part of the a micro service ecosystem.

You can use like an API it to serve resources encoding your results on JSON or you can use it to manage authentication sessions of your users and interact with other kind of micro services

As personal comment I dont like how Cake handle the View layer of the MVC but you can server your content as JSON and handle the data with a JS client or even an mobile app

Comment: Thanks. Personally, I started to love this framework because of the way it handles convention over configuration. No other PHP framework comes close. But somehow, I feel that not enough documentation is provided in terms of examples of how to use CakePhp in loosely coupled MVC scenarios. All the new generation of programmers are focusing on REST based and microservice cloud based architecture and CakePhp... despite having a possibility of usage in this area... kind of lacks focus in this area.

Comment: Yes Cake is very intuitive for the beginners but if you focus on how Cake works you will be able to apply all that acknowledgment to make it work as you wish... and eventually you are going to found his limitations. Good luck